# How could HRESULT appear in an MIDL file?

Tags: c#, c++, com, interop

I am developing some COM interfaces with IDL files. Some interface methods return HRESULT, but I have checked the [MIDL language reference on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367088(v=VS.85).aspx), there's not a clue of HRESULT. So where could I find the official definition of this data type?

### Update

Thanks to Shog9, I found it in **wtypes.idl**. I paste it here for other's view:

```
    ...
    cpp_quote("#ifndef _HRESULT_DEFINED")
    cpp_quote("#define _HRESULT_DEFINED")
    #if defined(_STRICT_HRESULT)
    typedef struct _HRESULT_STRUCT {
            DWORD Data1;
    } HRESULT_STRUCT, *PHRESULT_STRUCT;
    typedef PHRESULT_STRUCT HRESULT;
    #else // defined(_STRICT_HRESULT)
    cpp_quote("#ifdef __midl")
    typedef LONG HRESULT;
    ...
```

However, when I use the DWORD or LONG explicitly in my IDL files, the MIDL compiler will report an error saying:

```
"error MIDL2269: procedures in an object interface must return an HRESULT"
```

Kind of ridiculous...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any practical .idl file should start with

```
import "oaidl.idl";
import "ocidl.idl";
```

Which declares essential types.  Like HRESULT and VARIANT.  Etcetera.

Comment: I have checked these 2 files. Not found the definition of HRESULT. Do I miss something?

Comment: You probably missed all the include directives in those files.  Do you have a *real* problem?

Answer (score 4):

It's actually just an alias for `DWORD` (which is an alias for unsigned long). It's #defined for MIDL in wtypes.idl, which [as Hans notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450821/how-could-hresult-appear-in-an-midl-file/3450888#3450888) is brought in by the standard import mechanism.

The purpose of `HRESULT` is to represent return codes in a consistently recognizable manner - success and failure can be identified regardless of the source or other information encoded in the value, and certain system-defined values are given special meaning when coupled with standard interfaces. [See MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb446131.aspx) for details.